# Modify an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've got an array generated thanks to a MySQL query to my database it's like it :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_device] => 1
                    [device_name] => iPhone 5
                    [device_brand] => Apple
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_device] => 2
                    [device_name] => iPhone 4/4S
                    [device_brand] => Apple
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_device] => 3
                    [device_name] => Galaxy S4
                    [device_brand] => Samsung
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_device] => 4
                    [device_name] => Galaxy S3
                    [device_brand] => Samsung
                )

        )

)
```

I'd like it to be like this :

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_device] => 1
                    [device_name] => iPhone 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_device] => 2
                    [device_name] => iPhone 4/4S
                )

        )

    [Samsung] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_device] => 3
                    [device_name] => Galaxy S4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_device] => 4
                    [device_name] => Galaxy S3
                )

        )

)
```

I just don't understand the logic in those array (I'm pretty sure it's because I'm stressed and really busy though). Can someone help me with that ?

Another solution would be to change the MySql query maybe, I'm obtaining this array thanks to a php Class in which I use two methods :

```
public static function getDevicesBrands()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT '._DB_PREFIX_.'device.device_brand
    FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'device';
    $rq = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);
    return ($rq);
}

public static function getDevicesByBrand($brand)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT id_device, device_name, device_brand 
    FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'device
    WHERE '._DB_PREFIX_.'device.device_brand = "'.$brand.'"';
    $rq = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);
    return ($rq);
}
```

In my controller I get the shown array using that piece of code :

```
$device_brand = Device::getDevicesBrands();
$row = count($device_brand);
$devices_by_brand = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= $row - 1; $i++) {
    array_push($devices_by_brand, Device::getDevicesByBrand($device_brand[$i]['device_brand']));
}

echo"<pre>";
print_r($devices_by_brand);
echo"</pre>";
```

Comment: I think you solved it, so what's the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `for`-loop in controller should do the trick:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $row - 1; $i++) {
    $brand = $device_brand[$i]['device_brand'];
    $devices_by_brand[$brand] = Device::getDevicesByBrand($brand);
}
```

Comment: Just thanks... You're awesome it's so simple, I just have to train with arrays.

I'll accept your answer once it's possible (you answered within 7 minutes xD).